# Remove ui-menu-icon from main navigation

Tags: magento-2.1, navigation, ui

I am trying to find where this menu Icon is generated in the magento system. I would like to remove it. This menu is generated based on my product categories. When its clicked it shifts the word Rental  to the right. If anyone knows where its coming from that would be helpful!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is generated by the [Menu widget](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_menu.html), which is an extension of the [jQuery UI menu](https://api.jqueryui.com/menu/).

So to prevent this markup from being added you will either need to not use the jQuery UI based menu, or to extend the JS to remove it.

Both of those solutions are overkill, so I'd suggest setting `display: none;` via CSS, or if you really don't want it in the markup then remove it via JS.

You can view the responsible code here:

```
File: lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js
Line: 11726

submenuCarat = $( "<span>" )
    .addClass( "ui-menu-icon ui-icon " + icon )
    .data( "ui-menu-submenu-carat", true );
```

Comment: .navigation li.level0 span .ui-menu-icon  { display: none;  } 

Or should I add 

$('.ui-menu-icon').css('display','none');

Comment: I'd go with the first one, setting `display: none;` will achieve the results you want. I would only use JS if you really needed the markup removing.